# Rest Adapter set dynamic host and headers depending on route

Tags: ember.js

I have an existing ember application whose APIs are being updated and shifted on different server. So, currently some routes need old API and some need new API. I don't want to create separate adapters for these routes. I want to manage both new and old APIs with application.js adapter and serializer.

On serializer end, i have made a transformer mixin which is fine. But on adapter `(adapters/application.js)` i cannot set host and headers dynamically based on route. For `pathForType` i have used a method in mixin which returns new/old API path based o route name. Cannot set header and host this way.

Can someone suggest a way to handle this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution myself. What is did is used the **`ajaxOptions`** method to update the headers dynamically as required. Also, commented out the **`host`** property and in the same **`ajaxOptions`** block got the host url dynamically from mixin and appended to url.

```
ajaxOptions: function (url, type, hash) {
     let apiHostUrl=this.getApiHost(routeName);
     hash = hash || {};
     hash.url = apiHostUrl + url;
}
```

Hope this might be useful for someone in similar situation as me.

Comment: For anyone reading this, ajaxOptions is a private api and is documented here: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/methods/ajaxOptions?anchor=ajaxOptions&show=inherited%2Cprivate